# Pass an array to a C# DLL from C++ DLL

Tags: c#, arrays, dll, c++-cli

I am trying to handle a C++ DLL which in turn connects to a C# DLL.
My problem is when I want to send or receive arrays between C++ and C# DLLs.
I have created the C# DLL and C++ DLL, so I can modified all the files. Within the C# DLL, I must necessarily have an array of `string` an another of `double` because that is where I make use of other functions unrelated to this question. (The declaration of the function that I have to use in C# DLL is `Error SetMultipleChannelValues(string[] names,double[] values)`.

I am using CLI in Visual Studio 2015 to compile and generate all DLLs and projects.

**Here it is the C# code that I have:**

```
public static Error SetMultipleSignals(string[] signals, double[] values)
    {
        Error error = null;

        error = workspace.SetMultipleChannelValues(signals, values);
        if (error.IsError)
            Console.WriteLine("[DLL] Error in SetMultipleChannelValues(). Code: " + error.Code + ". Message: " + error.Message);

        return error;
    }
```

**Here it is the C++ code that I have:**

```
bool setMultipleSignals(double* setSignal_values)
{
    array<double, DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE> values;
    for (int index = 0 ; index < DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE ;index++)
    {
        values[index] = *(setSignal_values + index);
    }

    if (!veristand_wrapper_cs::VeriStand_dll::SetMultipleSignals(setSignals_path, values)) // This is the call to C# function
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**Here it is the C++ header that I have:**

```
#pragma once

#define VERISTAND_WRAPPER_CPP __declspec(dllexport)

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;

#using "veristand_wrapper_cs.dll"   // This is the C# DLL
#define DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE  100

extern "C" VERISTAND_WRAPPER_CPP bool setMultipleSignals(double* setSignal_values); // This         function is called from API C++
```

I pass the double array with a pointer to `double` as a parameter from my C++ application, but I have to pass to C# DLL an array, so I have tried to build a whole array of double before pass it.
The array `setSignals_path` is created as a global array in this C++ DLL as `array<String^, DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE> setSignals_path;`.

The problem is that the call of C# function provides me an error that says that I can not call the function with these arguments. It expects `array<System::String^> ^signals, array<double> ^values` and I am passing `std::array<System::String^, 100Ui64>, std::array<double, 100Ui64>`

The concept of my idea is simple. From the C++ API, pass a pointer to the array of doubles, so that the function of my DLL in C++ passes the array of doubles and strings to the DLL of C#, and it returns the array of modified doubles to be able to indicate to the API from C++ that the values ​​have been modified from that memory address.

Would anyone know how to approach this problem or how to do it in some other way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using c++/cli. So you can actually use .Net types in native code.

In C++/cli you need to explicitly declare if a variable is a reference, that is what the `^` is for. Your arrays is declared without this, but your method needs a reference. You will also need to allocate your array on the managed heap. So your array should probably be declared as

```
array<double>^ values = gcnew array< double>(DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE);
```

But it was a while ago I coded c++/cli, so I may have missed something. See [How to use arrays in c++/cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-use-arrays-in-cpp-cli?view=msvc-170). It also looks like you may be able to use [`ref new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/ref-new-gcnew-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170) instead of gcnew

Comment: Hi JonasH, thanks for your answer, but this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use following.  The size of array must be 100, or add another parameter before the string array indicating length.  The string in code is a byte array terminating with '\0'.  c++ must use a method that will read the null terminated string.  A double is 8 bytes so the 100 double can be consecutive memory locations (800 bytes).

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct StringArray
    {
        public IntPtr[] unmanagedArray;
    }
    public struct DoubleArray
    {
        public double[] values;
    }


   public static Error SetMultipleSignals(IntPtr signals, IntPtr values)
    {
        const int DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE = 100;
        StringArray stringStruct = new StringArray();
        stringStruct.unmanagedArray = new IntPtr[DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE];

        Marshal.PtrToStructure(signals, stringStruct);

        string[] strArray = new string[DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE; i++)
        {
            strArray[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(stringStruct.unmanagedArray[i]);
        }
        DoubleArray dArray = new DoubleArray();
        dArray.values = new double[DEFAULT_SETSIGNAL_SIZE];
        dArray = Marshal.PtrToStructure<DoubleArray>(values);
        return null;
```

Here is going the other way.

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct StringArray
        {
            public IntPtr[] unmanagedArray;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] strArray = { "Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3"};


            StringArray stringStruct = new StringArray();
            stringStruct.unmanagedArray = new IntPtr[strArray.Length];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
            {
                stringStruct.unmanagedArray[i] = Marshal.StringToBSTR(strArray[i]);
            }


            IntPtr unmanagedArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(stringStruct));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(stringStruct, unmanagedArray, false);
        }
```

Comment: I left out instruction to copy managed array to unmanaged space. Will update.